# Getting dependency error in rust Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, chatbot, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I am getting some dependencies version errors in rust.

I am fairly new to rust so I do not have any idea how to check for compatible updates between multiple dependencies.

It will be great if someone can resolve this issue and let me know how to manage dependencies.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "chatbot"
version = "0.2.3"
authors = ["Joe Wilm <joe@jwilm.com>"]
license = "MIT"
description = "An extensible chatbot"
documentation = "https://docs.rs/chatbot"
repository = "https://github.com/jwilm/chatbot"
keywords = ["chat", "bot", "extensible"]
readme = "README.md"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
all-features = true

[dependencies]
regex = "0.1"
rustc-serialize = "0.3"
getopts = "0.2"
irc = { version = "0.12", optional = true }
slack = { version = "0.18.0", optional = true }

[features]
default = []
irc-adapter = ["irc"]
slack-adapter = ["slack"]
```

I tried with versions suggested by VS Code but it did not work.

Error which I am getting after I do cargo-run is:

```
failed to select a version for the requirement `security-framework 
= "^0.1.13"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 2.8.2, 2.8.1, 2.8.0, ...     
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `native-tls v0.1.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `native-tls = "^0.1.2"` of package `tungstenite v0.2.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `tungstenite = "^0.2.0"` of package `slack v0.18.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `slack = "^0.18.0"` of package `chatbot v0.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using old versions of the `slack` and `irc` crates. Both depend on an old version of `native-tls` (`v0.1`) in their dependency trees. `native-tls v0.1` depends on a very old version of the `security-framework` crate (`v0.1`). All versions of `security-framework v0.1` have been yanked from [crates.io](https://crates.io), see here: https://crates.io/crates/security-framework/versions. I assume this is due to a security issue in those versions. Because the `v0.1` version of `security-framework` is yanked, you can't download it from crates.io anymore, causing the dependency error during compilation.

You can fix this by updating your `irc` and `slack` dependencies to their latest versions:

```ini
[package]
name = "chatbot"
version = "0.2.3"
authors = ["Joe Wilm <joe@jwilm.com>"]
license = "MIT"
description = "An extensible chatbot"
documentation = "https://docs.rs/chatbot"
repository = "https://github.com/jwilm/chatbot"
keywords = ["chat", "bot", "extensible"]
readme = "README.md"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
all-features = true

[dependencies]
regex = "0.1"
rustc-serialize = "0.3"
getopts = "0.2"
irc = { version = "0.15", optional = true }
slack = { version = "0.25", optional = true }

[features]
default = []
irc-adapter = ["irc"]
slack-adapter = ["slack"]
```

Be aware that updating these dependencies is likely to break your code, since there are probably API changes in between your current and the latest version of these crates.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your dependencies especially

```ini
[dependencies]
irc = { version = "0.15.0", optional = true }
slack = { version = "0.25.0", optional = true }
```

seem to be troublesome.